# VB.NET Linklabel gives 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: vb.net

I have a few linklabels that I use for email addresses. At run time I can click on the link and it opens a new email with the address exactly like I want it to. But when I close the email and want to click on it again it gives me the System.NullReferenceException.

I am still learning so it is likely I am making a rookie error somewhere. I understand what the error means but the label already have text data linked to it so I do not understand why it then gives the Null error on the 2nd try. Does it need to be reloaded or refreshed?

```
    Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(CurDir() & "\" & "AdelphiContacts.txt")

    linklabel1.Text = reader.ReadLine()


    With outMsg
        .To = linklabel1.Text
    End With

    'Display email
    outMsg.Display()

    reader.Close()
```

The error comes up when I debug at

```
    .To = linklabel1.Text
```

For outMsg it comes from

```
     Dim outApp As Application = New Application
     Dim outMsg As MailItem = outApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
```

Comment: You need to post your code. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Has outMsg had a new instance created. Show the code for this object please.

Comment: Did not want to have to much code in the message as I have seen on other questions there have been complaints of too much code. With outMsg all works fine and opens the email with the data. The 2nd time around it does not though.

Comment: Could do with seeing all the code in this instance for this method. What's the value of linklabel1.Text if you place a breakpoint on .To?

Comment: linklabel1.text at the moment only says "test" which is pulled from the text file.

Comment: Ok so my guess is outMsg has not been initialised second time round. Check what that is by placing a breakpoint on it. Could be you're disposing it. Can't tell without seeing more code.

Comment: I did what you said with the breakpoint and it does exactly that, on the 2nd time passing it throws the error. How do I then initialise the outMsg again?

Comment: I take it you're disposing the object at some point? It's been a while since I've used the MS Office objects but I would have through placing outMsg = outApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) just before you use it would work.

Comment: Thank you Jinx88909, I added it to the linklabel directly and that sorted it. Thank you for your patience and help.